# Why does mysqli_query return an error?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q = "INSERT INTO customers (username, email, pass, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$u', '$e','"  .  password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) .  "', '$fn', '$ln)";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

---

The structure of customers table.

```
id int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT  
username    varchar(45)         
email index     varchar(80)         
first_name  varchar(20)                 
last_name   varchar(40)         
pass        varchar(255)    
date_created    timestamp   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
type    enum('member', 'administer')
```

---

Then, `mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)` returns -1.

Tell me what is a problem.

Comment: 1.Please add code here not image. 2. INSERT just returns true or false. to actually return something useful, you will need a SELECT or similar query. there is no result to fetch with INSERT.

Comment: $q = "INSERT INTO customers (username, email, pass, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$u', '$e','"  .  password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) .  "', '$fn', '$ln)";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

Comment: Please add in your question not in comment.And pls add full code.

Comment: this return value means there was an error somewhere, you can use to `mysqli_error()` to view last error.

Comment: First, don't post code as an image. Can't copy/paste for testing and is hard to read. 2nd, use prepared statements and bind the variables before execution to avoid SQL injection. Lastly, show the schema of the table(s) involved in your question so we have a clue about the problems you might have with the SQL syntax.

Comment: Don't put the code in the comments, edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Are you saying mysqli_affected_rows() isn't acceptable to INSERT query?

Comment: i think u forgot to add `'` here `'$fn', '$ln)`

Comment: Oh my got,thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

In the last value to insert you have missed a '.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO customers (username, email, pass, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$u', '$e','"  .  password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) .  "', '$fn', '$ln)";
```

Try using this one

```
$q = "INSERT INTO customers (username, email, pass, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$u', '$e','"  .  password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) .  "', '$fn', '$ln')";
```